# Model evaluation using Akaike's Information Criterion, Bayesian Information Criterion and Future Prediction Error Criterion

Tags: bayesian, model-evaluation, information-theory, linear-dynamical-system

I have come up with 5 different models for a dynamical process which has 3 parameters. In order to decide which model is the best, I am using these criterions from information theory: Akaike's Information Criterion, Bayesian Information Criterion and Future Predction Error Criterion. I have read that the best model is the one which gives the smallest number in any of the above criteria. Suppose the BIC gives for example: $\ -100, \ -150 $ for the first and second model respectively. Can I conclude that the second model is better because it gives smaller result for BIC ?

The formula I use for the calculation of the BIC is:

$$ BIC = Nln(I(\theta)) + nln(N) $$

where:

$\ n: $ number of parameters

$\ N: $ total number of data

$\ I(\theta): $ mean squared error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not exactly the [canonical formula for the BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion). Usually, the BIC of a model $\mathcal{M}$ for data $\mathcal{D}$ is computed as

$$
BIC_{\mathcal{M}}(\mathcal{D}) = -2 \log (p(\mathcal{D}|\hat{\theta},\mathcal{M})) + k_{\mathcal{M}} \log (n)
$$

where $\hat{\theta}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $p(\mathcal{D}|{\theta},\mathcal{M})$, $n$ is the number of data points in $\mathcal{D}$, and $k_{\mathcal{M}}$ the number of free parameters in $\mathcal{M}$. Indeed, the model with the **lowest** BIC is the best one to explain your data. The AIC works similarly, but uses a different penalty for the number of parameters.